# Mysql order by city, province and country

Tags: mysql

```
Table: entity
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ city_id    ║ province_id ║ country_id ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ NULL       ║ 654         ║ 12         ║
║  2 ║ 17782      ║ 654         ║ 12         ║
║  3 ║ 17782      ║ 654         ║ 12         ║
║  4 ║ 16762      ║ NULL        ║ 32         ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

I have got following three values to query the `entity` table:

`city_id = 17782` `province_id = 654` and `country_id = 12`

Now I want to sort the results by provided values in sequence 
**city_id > province_id > country_id**.

1. If city_id is not null and city_id = 17782 then it should come first in the result set
2. if city_id is null then it will sort by province_id = 654 
   provided that province_id is not null
3. If province_id is null then it will fall back to country_id = 12

I have this query which doesn't work as expected

```
select * from entity 
order by city_id is null, city_id <> 17782, 
province_id is null, province_id <> 654, country_id <> 12
```

Gives following result set

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ city_id    ║ province_id ║ country_id ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║  2 ║ 17782      ║ 654         ║ 12         ║
║  3 ║ 17782      ║ 654         ║ 12         ║
║  4 ║ 16762      ║ NULL        ║ 34         ║
║  1 ║ NULL       ║ 654         ║ 12         ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Note the province_id with null value comes first while value 654 should come first, this is because of first condition city_id is null

Desired Result

```
╔════╦════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║ id ║ city_id    ║ province_id ║ country_id ║
╠════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║  2 ║ 17782      ║ 654         ║ 12         ║
║  3 ║ 17782      ║ 654         ║ 12         ║
║  1 ║ NULL       ║ 654         ║ 12         ║
║  4 ║ 16762      ║ NULL        ║ 34         ║
╚════╩════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: Please try this : select * from entity 
 order by
    case when city_id = 17782 and province_id is not null then 1
   when city_id is null and province_id = 654 then 2
   when province_id is null and country_id = 12 then 3
   else 4 end

Comment: Can you show the desired result, so we can tell if we get it right?

Comment: You can't get that result from the sample input you showed. There's no row with `city_id = 16762` and `province_id = NULL`

Comment: @Barmar I have updated the desired result

Comment: is it not more logical to order by country, provice, city ? Your table will show all country together, it will show all province together and all cities together... just add desc or asc where needed to move the null value to the bottom. select * from entity order by country_id ASC, provice_id DESC, city_id DESC

Comment: @sliver I know i can get results sorted by all columns, but what if you want city_id with specific value to come first, if city_id is null then province_id should come first with specific value and so on for country

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from entity  
order by (city_id <=> 17782 OR province_id <=> 654 OR country_id <=> 12) DESC, 
         city_id <=> 17782 DESC, province_id <=> 654 DESC, country_id <=> 12 DESC;
```

The first part of the `ORDER BY` gets all the desired values to the front of the results, then the remaining parts order within them by the priority city, province, country.

I use the [null-safe equal operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to) `<=>`, so that `city_id = NULL` won't force that row out of the `province_id` ordering.

Comment: Please check the screenshot of result set: http://imageresize.org/Output/952732c1-d3f3-4c95-ba9a-9632e771068b.jpg

Comment: Try now, I've changed to `<=>` comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Try this following and let me know thanks.

```
select * from entity 
order by 
   case when city_id = 17782 and province_id is not null then 1 
        when city_id is null and province_id = 654 then 2 
        when province_id is null and country_id = 12 then 3 
   else 4 end
```

Comment: I tried this, city_id with null values come first even if their value is 17782, same case for province